# Override Method Return Value

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mocking

I want a certain method of an object to always return a certain value when running unit tests.  For example.

- Object A has Method A that normally returns "Foo"
- Object B instantiates Object A and calls Method A in Method B
- Unit Test A calls Method B

In the unit test I want Method A to return "Bar", but in all other cases I want to return "Foo".

I don't think Mocking will work since you need to have the object reference ahead of time (at least with Moq).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocking is the tool to use for this kind of scenario. Most mocking framework will enable you to mock object A without creating the instance. For example moles from Microsoft will enable you to implement the scenario you describe.

[Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/)

Answer (score 2):

If possible you should pass in Object A as a dependency into Object B. The dependency you can then mock out using Moq and make it return `Bar` when method A is called.

If object creation of A is done internally in B, then object B is not testable for this part (hence why you should pass in your dependencies).